# C# removing an object Completely(no collision)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am making a brick break game in c# windows form in which I need to remove a picture box when the ball(picture box) collide with it........
I have tried hide, dispose remove control and even making it equal to null but all of them just hide it and doesn't make it vanished completely means that there is still collision.....
here is my code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
  {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public int spx =10;
     public int spy = 10;
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Cursor.Hide();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        paddle.Top = background.Bottom - (background.Bottom / 10);
        if(paddle.Left > background.Left)
        {
            paddle.Left += 0;
        }

     }
     private void Form1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
     { 

     }
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ball.Left += spx;
        ball.Top += spy;
        paddle.Left = Cursor.Position.X - (paddle.Left / Width);
        if(ball.Left <= background.Left)
        {
            spx = -spx;
        }
        if (ball.Right >= background.Right)
        {
            spx = -spx;
        }
        if (ball.Top <= background.Top)
        {
            spy = -spy;
        }
        if (ball.Bottom >= background.Bottom)
        {
            spy = -spy;
        }


        if (paddle.Top <= ball.Bottom && paddle.Top >= ball.Top && ball.Left >= paddle.Left && ball.Right <= paddle.Right)
        {
            spy = -spy;
        }
        if (pictureBox.Top <= ball.Bottom && pictureBox.Bottom >= ball.Top && ball.Left <= pictureBox.Right && ball.Right >= pictureBox.Left)
        {
            spy = -spy;
            background.Controls.Remove(pictureBox);
            pictureBox = null;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Have you also tried moving its position so it is no longer in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your code that checks for collisions is hard-coded to look at `pictureBox`.  Making it invisible doesn't change that.

If you want to use the `Visible` property of `pictureBox` to hide it, then you should change those `if` conditions to ignore it if it isn't visible:

```
if (pictureBox.Visible && (pictureBox.Top <= ball.Bottom && pictureBox.Bottom >= ball.Top && ball.Left <= pictureBox.Right && ball.Right >= pictureBox.Left))
    {
        spy = -spy;
        pictureBox.Visible = false;
    }
```